# Middle @client.event doesn't work? Why is it like this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I didn't really know how to explain in the title, but basically I have 3 @client.event and always the 2nd one (the one in the middle) never works.
Here's my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import random
from random import choice


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("hi!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$ask'):
           possible_responses = [
               'It is certain.',
               'It is decidedly so.',
               'Without a doubt.',
               'Yes - definitely.',
               'You may rely on it.',
               'As I see it, yes.',
               'Most likely.',
               'Outlook good.',
               'Yes.',
               'Signs point to yes.',
               'Reply hazy, try again.',
               'Ask again later.',
               'Better not tell you now.',
               'Cannot predict now.',
               'Concentrate and ask again.',
               'Don\'t count on it.',
               'My reply is no.',
               'My sources say no.',
               'Outlook not so good.',
               'Very doubtful.',
           ]
           await message.channel.send(random.choice(possible_responses))
```

and then I also have client.run(token).
I'm also new to discord.py and python in general. Hopefully what I said made sense.

I tried the code above. I was expecting the middle command to work like the others.

Edit: And it also doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
... def ...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```

That is, you `def`ined the same function twice.
So the last one overwrote the prior version.
The middle one is no more.

Either combine the logic of both into a single function,
or choose a distinct function name.

---

There's a `dict` that implements the module namespace.
It now has an `"on_message"` entry in it.

The presence of any `@` decorators won't change its name -- it's
still `"on_message"`.
Decorators *do* affect the generated bytecode.

---

Let's declare a new variable:

```
x = 42
x = 43
```

> And it also doesn't give any errors.

That's right.
It's a feature that overwriting the old value
(binding a new value to existing name)
will silently succeed, without raising any errors.

Similarly when we `def` a function and then `def` it again
with some new and improved version of the function code.

If you want warnings, run a source code linter, such as
"$ [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff) *.py"

Comment: _you `def`ined the same function twice. So the last one overwrote the prior version_ Is this true even when both functions have a decorator?

Comment: @JohnGordon, no. (Updated the answer text.)